# Выборка переменных и текста

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, text

Допустим есть следующий текст:

```
{first_variable} text-text text-text
{second_variable} 
footer footer  {other_variable} footer
```

Как можно наименее затратней получить массив и переменных и текста?

Т.е. массивы должны выглядеть так:

```
['{first_variable}', '{second_variable}', '{other_variable}']
[' text-text text-text
', ' 
footer footer  ', ' footer']
```

Я пока только придумал пропускать текст через [2 регулярных выражения](http://jsfiddle.net/2sX4h/1/). Но чую, что можно проще.

Comment: Решение в две строки, куда уж проще-то? Только регулярки чуть-чуть [подпрваить][1], сделатьих нежадными. А то ваши [криво обрабатывают][2] несколько переменных в одной строке.


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/2sX4h/3/
  [2]: http://jsfiddle.net/2sX4h/2/

Comment: @fori1ton вдруг одной регуляркой можно вытягивать и переменные и текст?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если хотите одной регуляркой, то можно так:

```
source.match(/({(.*?)})|([^{]+)/g)
```

Но тогда придётся вручную определять, является ли элемент переменной или строкой.

http://jsfiddle.net/2sX4h/5/

Comment: Ага, а проверять можно по первому и последнему символу. Надо посмотреть, что быстрее.

Comment: А обязательно разбирать строку на переменные и текст? Может `replace` подойдёт? Как предполагается использовать разобранную строку?

Comment: @fori1ton переделываю https://github.com/lampaa/NodeSmarty

Надо шоб быстрее всех работало :D 

По сути переменные и текст разделяются на 2 массива. Дальше с переменными происходит какая-то работа, а в конце всё склеивается.

Comment: @fori1ton http://jsperf.com/11231231wee3

Comment: А смысл разделять токены на два массива, если в них нет информации о порядке следования токенов? Ведь возможна ситуация, когда за переменной следует без разделителей другая переменная:

    {var1}{var2}text1{var3}text2

Тогда от массивов вида

    vars = ['{var1}', '{var2}', '{var3}'];
    texts = ['text1', 'text2'];

толку будет мало. Особенно если часть из них не переменные, а инструкции.

Comment: Посмотрел ваш код. В предыдущем комментарии я был неправ. Буду думать дальше.

Comment: @fori1ton да, не проверил. Тогда отпадает способ.